# Try/catch does not seem to have an effect

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am new to powershell, and I am trying to add error handling via try/catch statements, but they don't seem to actually be catching the error. This is powershell v2 CP3.

```
$objComputer = $objResult.Properties;
$strComputerName = $objComputer.name
write-host "Checking machine: " $strComputerName

try
{
    $colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputerName -Credential $credentials
    foreach ($objItem in $colItems) 
    {
        write-host "Bank Label: " $objItem.BankLabel
        write-host "Capacity: " ($objItem.Capacity / 1024 / 1024)
        write-host "Caption: " $objItem.Caption
        write-host "Creation Class Name: " $objItem.CreationClassName      
        write-host
    }
}
Catch 
{
    write-host "Failed to get data from machine (Error:"  $_.Exception.Message ")"
    write-host
}
finally 
{ }
```

When it fails to contact a specific machine, I get this in console, and not my clean catch message:

> `Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is
>
>   unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>
>   0x800706BA) At Z:\7.0 Intern
>
>   Programvare\Powershell\Get memory of
>
>   all computers in AD.ps1:25 char:34
>
>   +         $colItems = get-wmiobject <<<<  -class "Win32_PhysicalMemory"
>
>   -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputerName -Credential
>
>   $credentials
>
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject],
>
>   COMException
>
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :   GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I was able to duplicate your result when trying to run a remote WMI query.  The exception thrown is not caught by the Try/Catch, nor will a Trap catch it, since it is not a "terminating error".  In PowerShell, there are terminating errors and non-terminating errors .  It appears that Try/Catch/Finally and Trap only works with terminating errors.

It is logged to the $error automatic variable and you can test for these type of non-terminating errors by looking at the $? automatic variable, which will let you know if the last operation succeeded ($true) or failed ($false).

From the appearance of the error generated, it appears that the error is returned and not wrapped in a catchable exception.  Below is a trace of the error generated.

```
PS C:\scripts\PowerShell> Trace-Command -Name errorrecord  -Expression {Get-WmiObject win32_bios -ComputerName HostThatIsNotThere}  -PSHost
DEBUG: InternalCommand Information: 0 :  Constructor Enter Ctor
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand: 25857563
DEBUG: InternalCommand Information: 0 :  Constructor Leave Ctor
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand: 25857563
DEBUG: ErrorRecord Information: 0 :  Constructor Enter Ctor
System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord: 19621801 exception =
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): The RPC
server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
   at
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand.BeginProcessing()
errorId = GetWMICOMException errorCategory = InvalidOperation
targetObject =
DEBUG: ErrorRecord Information: 0 :  Constructor Leave Ctor
System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord: 19621801
```

A work around for your code could be:

```
try
{
    $colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_PhysicalMemory" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername $strComputerName -Credential $credentials
    if ($?)
    {
      foreach ($objItem in $colItems) 
      {
          write-host "Bank Label: " $objItem.BankLabel
          write-host "Capacity: " ($objItem.Capacity / 1024 / 1024)
          write-host "Caption: " $objItem.Caption
          write-host "Creation Class Name: " $objItem.CreationClassName      
          write-host
      }
    }
    else
    {
       throw $error[0].Exception
    }
```

Comment: You can make non-terminating errors get thrown by using: -ErrorAction "Stop" (or -EA "Stop" for short)

Comment: @JasonMArcher - Right you are!  Setting $ErrorActionPreference to 'Stop' as would work as well, but would have a global effect.

Comment: @Steven Murawski - unless you unset it in the FInally block.

Comment: @JasonMArcher not sure if this will work with a .net method call that throws an exception

Comment: .NET exceptions are always terminating, so they can be caught with no extra effort.

Comment: Don't forget to clear the error collection before executing the critical line. `$error.Clear()`

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I don't know why folks like `$Error[0]` so much. If you use `$_` in a catch you avoid having to clear the error cache and the risk of reporting an error encountered in the catch itself.

Answer (score 71):

If you want try/catch to work for all errors (not just the terminating errors) you can manually make all errors terminating by setting the `ErrorActionPreference`.

```
try {

   $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"; #Make all errors terminating
   get-item filethatdoesntexist; # normally non-terminating
   write-host "You won't hit me";  
} catch{
   Write-Host "Caught the exception";
   Write-Host $Error[0].Exception;
}finally{
   $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"; #Reset the error action pref to default
}
```

Alternatively... you can make your own try/catch function that accepts scriptblocks so that your try/catch calls are not as kludge. I have mine return true/false just in case I need to check if there was an error... but it doesn't have to. Also, exception logging is optional, and can be taken care of in the catch, but I found myself always calling the logging function in the catch block, so I added it to the try/catch function.

```
function log([System.String] $text){write-host $text;}

function logException{
    log "Logging current exception.";
    log $Error[0].Exception;
}


function mytrycatch ([System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] $try,
                    [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] $catch,
                    [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]  $finally = $({})){

    

# Make all errors terminating exceptions.
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
    
    # Set the trap
    trap [System.Exception]{
        # Log the exception.
        logException;
        
        # Execute the catch statement
        & $catch;
        
        # Execute the finally statement
        & $finally
        
        # There was an exception, return false
        return $false;
    }
    
    # Execute the scriptblock
    & $try;
    
    # Execute the finally statement
    & $finally
    
    # The following statement was hit.. so there were no errors with the scriptblock
    return $true;
}


#execute your own try catch
mytrycatch {
        gi filethatdoesnotexist; #normally non-terminating
        write-host "You won't hit me."
    } {
        Write-Host "Caught the exception";
    }
```

Comment: Trying using " ::Try divide by zero: $(0/0)" (and not use get-item filethatdoesntexist;). Then it doesn't catch that exception

Answer (score 17):

It is also possible to set the error action preference on individual cmdlets, not just for the whole script. This is done using the parameter ErrorAction (alisa EA) which is available on all cmdlets.

Example

```
try 
{
 Write-Host $ErrorActionPreference; #Check setting for ErrorAction - the default is normally Continue
 get-item filethatdoesntexist; # Normally generates non-terminating exception so not caught
 write-host "You will hit me as exception from line above is non-terminating";  
 get-item filethatdoesntexist -ErrorAction Stop; #Now ErrorAction parameter with value Stop causes exception to be caught 
 write-host "you won't reach me as exception is now caught";
}
catch
{
 Write-Host "Caught the exception";
 Write-Host $Error[0].Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

This is my solution. When Set-Location fails it throws a non-terminating error which is not seen by the catch block. Adding -ErrorAction Stop is the easiest way around this.

```
try {
    Set-Location "$YourPath" -ErrorAction Stop;
} catch {
    Write-Host "Exception has been caught";
}
```

Comment: `Get-ADDomainController -Discover -SiteName <name>` does the same nonsense, `-ErrorAction Stop` works there too.

Answer (score 5):

Adding "-EA Stop" solved this for me.

Comment: above solutions are complex, `Get-WmiObject` with `-ErrorAction Stop` works perfectly. Best solution here for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As stated in the comments, the following solution applies to PowerShell V1 only.

See [this blog post on "Technical Adventures of Adam Weigert"](http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2007/10/10/powershell-try-catch-finally-comes-to-life.aspx) for details on how to implement this.

Example usage (copy/paste from Adam Weigert's blog):

```
Try {
    echo " ::Do some work..."
    echo " ::Try divide by zero: $(0/0)"
} -Catch {
    echo "  ::Cannot handle the error (will rethrow): $_"
    #throw $_
} -Finally {
    echo " ::Cleanup resources..."
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to use [exception trapping](http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/).

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/06/17/traps-vs-try-catch.aspx

Pr this it should exist in V2 .

Comment: Try/Catch/Finally does not exist in V1 of PowerShell, but it is in V2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was only catching specific types of exceptions:

```
try
  {
    get-item -Force -LiteralPath $Path -ErrorAction Stop

    #if file exists
    if ($Path -like '\\*') {$fileType = 'n'}  #Network
    elseif ($Path -like '?:\*') {$fileType = 'l'} #Local
    else {$fileType = 'u'} #Unknown File Type

  }
catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] {$fileType = 'i'} #Inaccessible
catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException]{$fileType = 'x'} #Doesn't Exist
```

Added these to handle additional the exception causing the terminating error, as well as unexpected exceptions

```
catch [System.Management.Automation.DriveNotFoundException]{$fileType = 'x'} #Doesn't Exist
catch {$fileType='u'} #Unknown
```