# Powershell trap [Exception] is not catching my error

Tags: powershell, exception, powershell-trap

For some reason my script is not catching the exception when I run the following script against a file that does not exist. I based this code from examples I found on the web but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I would appreciate any tips or pointers on how to fix this.

Note: in the example below I've also tried

```
trap [Exception] {
```

but that didn't work either.

Here's the script:

```
function CheckFile($f) {

      trap {
        write-host "file not found, skipping".
        continue
      }

      $modtime = (Get-ItemProperty $f).LastWriteTime

      write-host "if file not found then shouldn't see this"
}


write-host "checking a file that does not exist"
CheckFile("C:\NotAFile")
write-host "done."
```

output:

```
PS > .\testexception.ps1
checking a file that does not exist
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\NotAFile' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\dleclair\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\lib\testexception.ps1:12 char:35
+       $modtime = (Get-ItemProperty <<<<  $f).LastWriteTime
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\NotAFile:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand

if file not found then shouldn't see this
done.
PS >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this:

```
trap { write-host "file not found, skipping";continue;}
$modtime = Get-ItemProperty c:\manoj -erroraction stop
```

Based on comments from OP:

I think you misunderstood what is being said in the article you have linked to:

> In this example, we used continue to caused execution to return to the
>   scope the trap is in and execute the next command. It’s important to
>   note that execution only returns to the scope of the trap, so if the
>   exception was thrown inside a function, or even inside a if statement,
>   and trapped outside of it … the continue will pick up at the end of
>   the nested scope.

So if you do something like this:

```
trap{ write-host $_; continue;}
throw "blah"
write-host after
```

`after` will be printed.

But if you do something like this:

```
trap{ write-host $_ ; continue}
function fun($f) {


      throw "blah"
      write-host after
}

fun
write-host "outside after"
```

`after` will NOT be printed, but `outside after` will be.

Alternatively, use a try-catch block:

```
      try{
      $modtime = (Get-ItemProperty $f -erroraction stop).LastWriteTime
      write-host "if file not found then shouldn't see this"
      }
      catch{
        write-host "file not found, skipping".
      }
```

Comment: Isn't it `-erroraction stop` if you want to see "file not found, skipping"

Comment: @JPBlanc - Thanks! Mean't to have stop only. Was trying something else with continue and pasted that.

Comment: I've modified my script to look as follows:

Comment: I've modified my script to look as follows:

    function CheckFile($f) {    
          trap {
            write-host "file not found, skipping"
            continue
          }
          $fprop = Get-ItemProperty $f -erroraction stop
          $modtime = $fprop.LastWriteTime

          write-host "if file not found then shouldn't see this, modtime = $modtime"
    }
    
    write-host "checking a file that does not exist"
    CheckFile("C:\NotAFile")
    write-host "done."

Comment: This is has stopped the exception from being dumped to the screen. However I'm still seeing the line that says 'write-host "if file not found then shouldn't see this" getting printed.

It was my understanding from reading the post at http://huddledmasses.org/trap-exception-in-powershell/ that trapping an exception should cause the execution to only start outside the scope where the trap was caught. So in this case I would have expected the write-host call inside the function to get skipped and things would start again from outside the function.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense now. Also, I found a very good Q&A on using try{} catch{} here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect. I didn't realize that Powershell supported try{} catch{} otherwise I would have chosen to do that right from the started. I've modified my code to use try{}/catch{} with the -erroraction flag set to 'stop' and it is now working beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `$ErrorActionPreference` to `SilentlyContinue` inside of the function or outside of the script (for global application) for `trap` to work. Alternatively (as mentioned above), set `-ErrorAction` common parameter to the same thing.