# Why are the errors slipping through TRY/CATCH Loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch

I got a simple loop which gets all the serial Numbers in the Server List;

## Start

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) 
{
    try
    {
        Get-WmiObject -computer $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem|Select Serial*
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "Invalid Server"
    }
}
```

## END

But, the output looks all ugly with following errors as well as the correct outputs for few servers.

Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable
Get-WmiObject : Access Denied  etc  (Isnt it the purpose of **Try/Catch** loop to eliminate those?)

Strangely soemtimes the output says "Invalid Server" too , so what exactly is the difference between errors and what are the limitations of Try/Catch loops?

What am i doing wrong here? Please if any questions.

Comment: I don't have a computer to test on atm, but look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect  .  I belive Your error is not a terminating-error. Try/Catch only catches does. They list some solutions there, including adding `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";` to make all errors terminating. Does that help?

Comment: Perfect, that answers my question, i should have searched little more ,thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the above code throw an exception, you can add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Get-WmiObject` line, like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -computer $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop | Select Serial*
```

See this article by Keith Hill: [distinction between "terminating" and "non-terminating" errors](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/effective-powershell-item-16-dealing-with-errors/).

Comment: @Darktux: it does stop on `RPC unavailable` error. I tested this solution against your particular scenario before posting this answer.

Comment: My bad, there must have been uncleared variables and thats why it showed RPC errors , now everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Graimer the line ***$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"*** did the trick and the output was clean without errors.