# PowerShell: try-catch not working

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that gets a list of file names from a file, searches a folder for the file names, archives them, and then does other stuff.

```
#make non-terminating errors behave like terminating errors (at script level)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#set the folder that has the list and the files
$some_path = "D:\some_folder\"
$archive = "D:\archive\"

#set the list file name
$file_list = $some_path + "file_list.txt"

#get the files that I'm searching for from this list file
$files_to_retrieve = Select String -Path $file_list -Pattern "something" | Select-Object Line

#get the number of files for this search string
$n = $file_list.Length - 1

#seed the while loop counter
$i = 0

#while loop to archive and modify the files
While ($i -le $n)
{
    #set the current file name
    $current_file = $path + $files_to_retrieve[$i].Line

    try
    {
        Copy-Item -Path $current_file -Destination $archive_path
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host ("file " + $files_to_retrieve[$i].Line + " not found")
    }

    $data = Get-Content $current_file

    #do modifications here
}
```

The try-catch isn't working as expected.  I have a file name in the file list that is not present in $some_path.  I was expecting try-catch to stop the execution and do the Write-Host.  Instead, it doesn't run the Write-Host and continues to the `$data = Get-Content $current_file` step, which is throwing a terminating error because the path doesn't exist for the missing file.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I would recommend you to put a write-host output into your try block and check whether the file that is not present is realy tried to get copied.

Comment: I just put this code outside of the current While loop and into its own While loop.  (If files are not existent when they should be, I don't want to even attempt to modify them.)  In this separate While loop, I put a Write-Host in the try block.  The Write-Host displays.  So, the try is indeed being attempted.  The Write-Host in the catch also displays.  That tells me that try is indeed encountering an error.  If I put an Exit (non-zero) at the end of the catch, the script stops.  If I don't, it continues with the next step in the While loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try/catch does not seem to have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect)

Answer (score 6):

Your first problem is the `try/catch` as you know. Taking a brief look at the [documentation for about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) you will see that..

> Use Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to respond to or handle **terminating 
>       errors** in scripts.

Your `Copy-Item` line is not throwing a terminating error. We fix that with the common parameter `-ErrorAction`

```
Copy-Item -Path $current_file -Destination $archive_path -ErrorAction Stop
```

So if there is a problem then the `Catch` block should be called. Assuming that was the real issue there.

---

You have another issue I think as well that might just be a typo. I see the following snippet more than once.

```
$file_list[$i].Line
```

Earlier you have declared  `$file_list` as "D:\some_folder\file_list.txt" which is a string. I think what you meant to have is below. The above code would be null since string dont have a line property. But the return from `Select-String` can!

```
$files_to_retrieve[$i].Line
```

Comment: In addition to the above : I sometimes also need to set the -WarningAction variable to stop (causing a terminating error) to catch warnings in Powershell since some "errors" are logged as warnings in some Powershell CMDlets.

Comment: Doesn't setting $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" at the script level negate the need to set -ErrorAction Stop in every try-catch?

Comment: @Matt: You are correct about my typo. I meant to write $files_to_retrieve[$i].Line.  I have updated the post.

Comment: Also, I tried the -ErrorAction Stop after the Copy-Item.  It's not working.  When I run the Copy-Item outside of the script, it throws a terminating error there.  But, when I run the script, it writes the statement in my catch (indicating that the catch is indeed being called), but doesn't actually terminate there.  It attempts the Get-Content and throws the terminating error there.  I suspect something about it being contained in my while loop is making it jump to the next cmdlet.

Comment: Setting -WarningAction Stop didn't have any effect either.

Comment: @user3100444 the catch is meant for you to address the error state. It wont stop the script from executing once it completes. In your code `$data = Get-Content $current_file` will _always_ execute. If you don't want it that way you need to change your code

Comment: @Matt:  Thank you!  I had thought all along that try-catch stops the script from executing once it completes.