# How to capture exception thrown by gem install in powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, rubygems

I'm trying to capture the exception thrown while installing gems, I see the error on the command window however I'm not able to capture the error in catch block, I would like to capture and log in logs file, below is the code.

```
try{

    $tiny= .\gem install --local c:\mypath\tiny_tds-2.1.5-x64-mingw321.gem
    
    if($tiny -eq $null){
        throw
    }
    Write-Host "Installation completed  :" $tiny
}
catch{
$string_err = $_ | Out-String
Write-Host "*****************************"
Write-Host $string_err
Write-Host "*****************************"
}
```

Error that I get on powershell command window

[image]

Comment: Try adding `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` at the top of your script. Assuming that works, then `if($tiny -eq $null){...}` is not needed at all

Comment: :) basically the exception you were seeing was a non-terminating one, hence why the `try` was not able to `catch` it. By changing your error preference to `Stop`, all errors will be treated as terminating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell: try-catch not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33456028/powershell-try-catch-not-working)