# Checking if a local user account/ group exists or not with Powershell

Tags: powershell

There are two parts to this question.

1. I want to check if a local user exists or not before I go ahead and create it.
   So far I've come up with a simple script to check if a local user exists or not.  Here's the script to check if a user exists before I go ahead and create it.

> ```
> $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force
> $op = Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "testuser1"}
> if ( -not $op)
>  {
>   New-LocalUser testuser1 -Password $password | Out-Null
>  }
> ```

I tested this one out on my setup and it works fine for the most part without throwing any exception. Is there a better, quicker way to check if a user exists ? Also, is the script I'm using foolproof i.e. would it be better to handle it using *ErrorAction* or using *try....catch* ?

I'll be using this script for checking more than a couple of user accounts before I go ahead and create them.

2. Why is $op different in the following cases ?

**CASE 1**

[image]

**CASE 2**

[image]

I understand that *Out-String* is the reason behind this difference in output but I would've expected the output to have been more than just *testuser1* in CASE 1.

I'm new to Powershell so can someone please help me understand why there's a difference in output ?

Comment: Please consider marking one answer as the solution to your question.

Answer (score 9):

Use Try/Catch, most of the time it's faster to just ask and let Powershell handle the searching ;)

Especially with Long User lists, retrieving all the users and then iterating trough all of them will slow things down, just asking for a specific user is much faster but you need to handle the error if the user does not exist.

See example below:

```
Clear-Host
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

#User to search for
$USERNAME = "TestUser"

#Declare LocalUser Object
$ObjLocalUser = $null

try {
    Write-Verbose "Searching for $($USERNAME) in LocalUser DataBase"
    $ObjLocalUser = Get-LocalUser $USERNAME
    Write-Verbose "User $($USERNAME) was found"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UserNotFoundException] {
    "User $($USERNAME) was not found" | Write-Warning
}
catch {
    "An unspecifed error occured" | Write-Error
    Exit # Stop Powershell! 
}

#Create the user if it was not found (Example)
if (!$ObjLocalUser) {
    Write-Verbose "Creating User $($USERNAME)" #(Example)
    # ..... (Your Code Here)
}
```

About outputting certain data, I recommend that you explicitly define what you want to output, this way their will be no surprises and it makes thing clearer in your code.

See the example below, I explicitly defined the 3 properties I wanted and then forced it into a Table-View, to finish I converted it to a string, so no surprises for me any more ;)

```
Get-LocalUser | Select Name, Enabled, PasswordLastSet | Format-Table | Out-String
```

Example output

```
Name               Enabled PasswordLastSet    
----               ------- ---------------    
Administrator        False                    
DefaultAccount       False                    
Gast                 False                    
Test-Gebruiker        True 24-12-2017 01:58:12
```

Comment: `Get-LocalUser` is not a terminating exception apparently so the `try/catch` wasn't working until I added `-ErrorAction Stop` to that cmd-let.  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476699/185123)

Comment: horrific code, don't use exceptions as control flow

Answer (score 5):

You can use measure to check if user exist

```
$op = Get-LocalUser | where-Object Name -eq "yourusername" | Measure
if ($op.Count -eq 0) {
     # DO SOMETHING
} else {
     # REPORT SOMETHING
}
```

Comment: Great solution. I compacted it slightly, and used it to check for a local group:

If ((Get-LocalGroup | ? Name -eq "YourGroupName" | Measure).Count -eq 0) {
    # Do something here if it doesn't exist, like create it
}

Answer (score 3):

The first line calls the Get-LocalUser commandlet and uses the Name parameter to Specify the user be searched for. If that user is found the assignment of the variable $UserID will happen. If Get-LocalUser cannot find the user then it errors out and no assignment happens. Specifying the ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" will tell PowerShell not to stop or alert that there if there was an error making the assignment.

The If($UserID) test will return True if the assignment of the Variable happened successfully and False if did not.

```
$UserID = Get-LocalUser -Name 'UserName' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($UserID){
   Write-Host 'User Found'
}else{
    Write-Host 'User Not Found'
} #end if user exists
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

`Write-Host` calls `ToString()` method implementation of an object behind the scenes.

`Write-Host $op`
is equivalent to

`Write-Host $op.ToString()`

`Get-LocalUser | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "testuser1"}` returns a `LocalUser` object. `LocalUser.ToString()` implementation returns `Name` property, that's why you see `testuser1` as output.

`Out-String` on the other hand, converts the whole output of the command, which is a table representation of `LocalUser` object with 3 properties.

In Case 2, you can only use that output as a `String` object, whereas in Case 1, `$op` is a `LocalUser` object that you can manipulate or access properties. For example, you can print more properties:

`Write-Host $op.Name, $op.Enabled, $op.Description`

In order to see all the properties/methods available on an object, run `Get-Member` cmdlet:

`$op | Get-Member`

Comment: Thanks@Mustafa, before I go ahead and mark your answer, can you please answer this ---> Is there a better, quicker way to check if a user exists ? Also, is the script I'm using foolproof i.e. would it be better to handle it using ErrorAction or using try....catch ?

Comment: Error handling depends on what you want to assure after running the script. One modification I would suggest is instead of piping into `Out-Null`, you can check whether `New-LocalUser` returned a valid `LocalUser` object. That way, you will know that the operation was successful.

Comment: Additional reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1#outputs

Answer (score 0):

The old style usage of `[ADSI]` and `WinNT:` is also a valid option even with PowerShell 7.
And it works equally well with local as well as with domain accounts.

But it's quite legacy.

```
$UserName = './TestUser'
$WinNtUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://$UserName,user"

if (! $WinNtUser.Name) {
  throw "User $UserName was not found"
}
```