# Write PowerShell console text to a file

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that connects to a DB and loops over some data.

After the script finishes or throws an error, I need to append whatever the text displayed in the console to a log file.

I couldn't achieve that using `Write-Output` because I don't want to save specific values, I just need the whole console text to be appended to a file.

Thank you.

EDIT :

In fact, the final result that I'm looking for, is a log file with timestamps, here is my code :

```
$server = "USER\SQLEXPRESS"
$database = "database_test"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection

#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

$DriveName = (get-location).Drive.Name
$extractDir = md -Force "$($DriveName):\csv\files"

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $connection.open();
    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [$($Row[0])]"
    $command.Connection = $connection

    (Get-Culture).NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = '.'
    (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()

    $extractFile = "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

I need to print each filename exported to csv (`$extractFile`) with a timestamp in a log file, and then if an error occurs, I need to print that too with a timestamp, and so on till the script finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with **[`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6)**, **[`try`/`catch`/`finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally)**, or writing your own code (to store the console output to a variable, and append a text file with the contents when required). Note the `-Append` parameter with `Start-Transcript`.

Without code, it's difficult to know which of these to recommend.

### Expanded

Now that you've added some code, see some additional info on each method. I'm not familiar with SQL via PowerShell so not sure what kind of output/errors you will be getting (regarding errors, specifically if there are terminating or non-terminating)

**Transcript**

`Start-Transcript` should go at the beginning, and `Stop-Transcript` at the end. This will log whatever is normally displayed on the console. Running `Start-Transcript` while a transcript is already being recorded will lead to a nasty error.

```
Start-Transcript -Path "c\temp\mylogfile.txt"

$server = "USER\SQLEXPRESS"
$database = "database_test"
$tablequery = "SELECT name from sys.tables"
...

...
    $extractFile = "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}

Stop-Transcript
```

---

**Terminating Errors**

Add `try`/`catch`/`finally` as appropriate. You can be lazy and add this over the whole code, or do it properly and wrap the parts that could lead to [**terminating** errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144385/5039142).

```
...
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    try{
        $connection.open();
        #Specify the output location of your dump file
        ...

        ...
        ...
        $extractFile = "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"
        $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
    }catch{
        # what to do if there is a terminating error
    }finally{
        # what to do whether there is an error or not

        if(Test-Path "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"){
            # simple check: if a file was created, no error... right?
            "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') $($Error[0])" | Out-File "c:\temp\mylogfile.txt" -Append
        }else{
            "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') $extractFile" | Out-File "c:\temp\mylogfile.txt" -Append
        }
    }
}
...
```

**No Terminating Errors**

Just add a line to export errors. Ensure you clear the automatic variable `$Error` each loop

```
...
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $Error.Clear()
    $connection.open();
    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    ...

    ...
    ...
    $extractFile = "$($extractDir)\$($Row[0]).csv"
    $DataSet.Tables[0]  | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

    # if there are no errors, write filename. Otherwise write errors
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Error){
        "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') $extractFile" | Out-File "c:\temp\mylogfile.txt" -Append
    }else{
        "$(Get-Date -f 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') $Error" | Out-File "c:\temp\mylogfile.txt" -Append
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I updated my question so you can see what I'm really trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6) for debugging purposes:

```
Start-Transcript -path "C:\temp\myTranscript.txt"
```

Add at the start of your script and get all the console output written into `C:\temp\myTranscript.txt`

Comment: It didn't work, and I've updated my question if you want to take a look.

Comment: Where did you put the `Start-Transcript`?

Comment: At the end of the script

Comment: Should be at the very beginning of the script

Comment: It says, he `File` param is invalid

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It should be -Path instead

Comment: Because `File` isn't a valid param for `Start-Transcript` - check the documentation link in the answer for the params and example use.