# If statement in PowerShell dependant on if RPC Server is unavailable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, rpc

I'm writing a script in PowerShell that ideally would gather information from another server.  If it's not able to reach that server, I want to prompt it to have the user manually enter the information.  I know how to do all of these, but I'm getting hung up when the RPC Server is unavailable.  I will also say that I know how to fix the error when it occurs, but I do not want to rely on my end users to have to go in and fix this.

As an example, if I run:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer 10.5.21.94
```

the result I get back is:

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer 10.5.21.94
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], 
COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I'm trying to find a way to write an `if` statement that will check to see if the RPC server is available or not, but I'm not sure what to check in order to create a true/false variable.  And again, I'm not really looking for someone to tell me how to write the if statement, I'm just trying to figure out any query I can run to determine if I can properly connect to this server and get a result back that can tell me to continue on or not.

Comment: You may want to look into using Test-WSMan (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/test-wsman?view=powershell-6) or using Try/Catch blocks.

Comment: check rpc port availability with PowerShell: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/runcmd/troubleshoot-rpc-with-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to get around it in an if-statement is just to ignore potential errormessages with Erroraction and use a -not statement to check whether it can reach the destination or not and then append a $false value to a variable if it can't.

See the below example.

```
$status = ""
if (!(Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName 10.5.21.94 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
Write-Host "Server is unavailable!"
$status += $false 
}

    else {
    Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName 10.5.21.94
    }

if ($status -eq $false) {
    $Server = Read-Host "Please enter the destionation"
    Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a suggestion for a Try/Catch block, but since this is not a terminating error, it didn't work initially.  Then I found this:

[Try/catch does not seem to have an effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142211/try-catch-does-not-seem-to-have-an-effect)

There is an answer in there about making all errors terminating:

```
try {

   $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"; #Make all errors terminating
   get-item filethatdoesntexist; # normally non-terminating
   write-host "You won't hit me";  
} catch{
   Write-Host "Caught the exception";
   Write-Host $Error[0].Exception;
}finally{
   $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"; #Reset the error action pref to default
```

}

This gave me exactly what I was looking for!